# How to "attach" links at the bottom of the menu?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, cross-browser

**How to "attach" links at the bottom of the menu?**

```
Codepen: https://codepen.io/yariknashivanold/pen/aeLqX
```

[image: example]

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

```
.footer-links-div {
position: absolute;
bottom: 15px;
}
```

Closed